# How to print text file to PDF file in Linux command line

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I have some Python source file that I would like to print to PDF for later reading
I used to do this with gedit, file by file
but there are a large number of .py file I would like to automate this process

How can I do this ?
Better with Syntax highlighting too, such as with gedit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this single command

```
$pandoc -o output.pdf input.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a2ps to format nicely as postscript and then ps2pdf (from Ghostscript) to convert the postscript to PDF.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on the syntax highlighting part ? a2ps doesn't seem to be able to add colors to the Python source code

Comment: I don't do Python myself, but a2ps is supposed to have a syntax highlighter mode for Python (with the `-E` option). If that doesn't work ... go wild with regexes and pdfLaTeX?

Comment: `a2ps` has syntax highlighting, I just don't think it uses colors. Also, be warned that `a2ps` lacks unicode support. By  "lacks" I mean it won't even degrade nicely with utf8 input, you have to convert it to, say, iso8859-15.

Answer (score 0):

you might encounter Problems with e.g. Umlaute (ÄÖÜ) or ß. If so, I suggest [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/727335/499418).